# Using Spring security filters in a OSGI bundle

Tags: java, web-services, spring-security, osgi, fuseesb

I need to secure a web service (based on CXF) with Spring Security.

I already have the web service working on Tomcat but the deployment on Fuse ESB is not working.
We have a Spring configuration file which contains the following content :

```
....
<sec:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    use-expressions="true">
    <sec:http-basic />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</sec:http>
...
```

When we deploy the web service on Tomcat, we use the following web.xml :

```
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

When we deploy the bundle on Fuse, since we don't have a web.xml, the web serice is not secure, i.e the spring security filter is not working.
My question is :

How do we declare Spring security fitlers in Fuse ESB ? i.e what is the equivalent of the few lines in the web.xml

Regards,

Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Cxf/Fuse ESB Services will be having it's own security implementation based on Standards. You can explore more on it on their project/product documentation. If you looking for a spring app on osgi platform, then explore Spring DM (Dynamic Module).